# I need to create monocrome .bmp signature file by using C++ code but not able to create

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I need to create monocrome .bmp signature file by using C++ code but not able to create. below is the code snippet.

```
bool SaveBMP ( BYTE* Buffer, int width, int height, long paddedsize, LPCTSTR bmpfile )
{
    // declare bmp structures 
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER info;

    // andinitialize them to zero
    memset ( &bmfh, 0, sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER ) );
    memset ( &info, 0, sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER ) );

    // fill the fileheader with data
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42;       // 0x4d42 = 'BM'
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfh.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + paddedsize;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = 0x36;      // number of bytes to start of bitmap bits

    // fill the infoheader

    info.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    info.biWidth = width;
    info.biHeight = height;
    info.biPlanes = 1;          // we only have one bitplane
    info.biBitCount = 1;        // RGB mode is 24 bits
    info.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    info.biSizeImage = 0;       // can be 0 for 24 bit images
    info.biXPelsPerMeter = 0x0ec4;     // paint and PSP use this values
    info.biYPelsPerMeter = 0x0ec4;     
    info.biClrUsed = 0;         // we are in RGB mode and have no palette
    info.biClrImportant = 0;    // all colors are important

    // now we open the file to write to
    HANDLE file = CreateFile ( bmpfile , GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ,
         NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
    if ( file == NULL )
    {
        CloseHandle ( file );
        return false;
    }

    // write file header
    unsigned long bwritten;
    if ( WriteFile ( file, &bmfh, sizeof ( BITMAPFILEHEADER ), &bwritten, NULL ) == false )
    {   
        CloseHandle ( file );
        return false;
    }
    // write infoheader
    if ( WriteFile ( file, &info, sizeof ( BITMAPINFOHEADER ), &bwritten, NULL ) == false )
    {   
        CloseHandle ( file );
        return false;
    }
    // write image data
    if ( WriteFile ( file, Buffer, paddedsize, &bwritten, NULL ) == false )
    {   
        CloseHandle ( file );
        return false;
    }

    // and close file
    CloseHandle ( file );

    return true;
}
```

**//when I run this code the created bitmap file is blank, signature is not being shown, only the background of signature file is able to show. **

Comment: I tried again to upload, and now able to upload the code.

Comment: So you can open the created file using an image editor without any error and it has the correct size but the content is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Monochrom bitmap requires a palette. In this case the palette size is 8 bytes (2 `RGBQUAD` values)

This extra 8 bytes should be added to `BITMAPFILEHEADER` file size.

After `BITMAPFILEHEADER`, you are working with `BITMAPINFOHEADER` which does not contain information about palettes. You have to use `BITMAPINFO` directly instead of `BITMAPINFOHEADER`

```
BITMAPINFO* bmpinfo = (BITMAPINFO*)malloc(palette_size + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
bmpinfo->bmiHeader = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 
    width, height, 1, bitcount, BI_RGB, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

If `Buffer` was not retrieved for a monochrome bitmap then you cannot simply change `bitcount` in this save function and expect everything to work.

```
if ( file == NULL )// <-error
{
    CloseHandle ( file );
    return false;
}
```

If [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) fails, the return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. You can find out these values from online documentation for API functions. The corrected version should be

```
if(file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    unsigned long bwritten;
    WriteFile(file, &bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &bwritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(file, bmpinfo, 8 + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &bwritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(file, Buffer, paddedsize, &bwritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(file);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: As you provided solution, I did change in the code, but the problem is still the same

Comment: //As you provided solution, I did change in the code, but the problem is still the same.monochrome File is being created but the signature is also removed, which is not expected.
which means only background of the pic is showing but the written on the background is removed.

Comment: *"I did change in the code"* is not a thing. You have to retrieve the buffer with the palette, or you have to add the palette if the buffer doesn't already include a palette.

Comment: I am very new in this thing, will you please help me to add the palette or will you explain how to retrieve the buffer with palette.

Comment: @Pankaj Palette is stored in `BITMAPINFO::bmiColors`. So this would initialize black/white palette: `bmpinfo->bmiColors[0] = {0,0,0,0}; bmpinfo->bmiColors[1] = {255,255,255,0};`.

Comment: thanks, but now I am getting spikes only in the image created, signature is still not able to seen.  Is there any solution ??
How can I see signature on this file??

Comment: You will not edit your question to give any additional information, so I can't help you that. This is about common sense, not about programming. I can't see what's on your screen. What is `width`, `height`, and `paddedsize`? At some point you must be calling `GetDIBits` or another method to obtain `Buffer`, what method did you use? What are the first few byte values in `Buffer`?